# Find a rank 1 matrix that better approximates a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

I have been working on a problem that asks the following: given a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
I need to find a matrix $M$ such that $rank(M) = 1$ that better approximates A. That is, I have to find a matrix of type
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
ra & rb & rc
\end{pmatrix},$$
such that the (real) values $a, b, c, r$ are such that it minimizes the following expression:

$(a^2) + (1-b)^2 + (3-c)^2 + (3-ra)^2 + (1-rb)^2 + (rc)^2$ (that is, the Frobenius norm of the difference $A-M$).

I know that I can do it by finding the minimmum of a function on 4 variables. But I was trying to find a better and clever way to do this, but I wasn't able to do so.

I would appreciate if you could come up with any ideas that could make this problem more easy to solve.

(Edit 1) Maybe an idea could arise out of a decomposition of this matrix into a product (for instance, LU decomposition or something like this).

Comment: I think SVD decomposition may help

Comment: I thought about this possibility, but I could not find a way to make it help. Could you give me a path or an extra-hint?

Comment: Hint: Focus on the largest singular value.

Comment: Thank you very much. You both helped me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Proof_of_Eckart%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Mirsky_theorem_(for_Frobenius_norm)) states that this approximation may be obtained using the singular value decomposition. In particular, we proceed as follows.

Begin by computing the singular value decomposition $A = U \Sigma V^T$, where
$$
A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 3\\
3 & 1 & 0}, \quad U = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}, \quad \Sigma = \pmatrix{\sqrt{11}\\ & 3}, \quad 
\\ V = \pmatrix{
3/\sqrt{22} & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{11}\\
\sqrt{2/11} & 0 & -3/\sqrt{11}\\
3/\sqrt{22} & -1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{11}}.
$$
Then, compute the rank-1 "truncated SVD" $M = U \hat \Sigma V$, where
$$
\hat \Sigma = \pmatrix{\sqrt{11}&0\\0&0}.
$$
Equivalently, we find
$$
M = \sqrt{11} \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1\\1}\pmatrix{3/\sqrt{22} & \sqrt{2/11} & 3/\sqrt{22}} 
\\ = \left(\begin{matrix}1.5 & 1.0 & 1.5\\1.5 & 1.0 & 1.5\end{matrix}\right).
$$